# EntityFramework = LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I've got some legacy code where there is a lot of raw SQL statements which I try to port to LINQ.

One of them looks like this

```
select s.Id, s.Name, s.Enabled, s.Tags, s.Description, s.ImageUrl, s.ImageFullUrl, sss.Id as StoneSupplierStoneId
from Stone s, StoneSupplierStone sss
where s.Id = sss.Stone_id and s.Enabled = 1
and sss.Id IN (select MAX(sss.Id)
                from Stone s, StoneSupplierStone sss
                where sss.StoneSupplier_id = 6142 
                and s.Id = sss.Stone_id and s.Enabled = 1
                group by s.Name, (case when sss.CustomStoneName is null then s.Name else sss.CustomStoneName end))
order by s.Name
```

which I managed to port to LINQ using something like this

```
var sssq = from s in Stone
            from sss in StoneSupplierStone
            where sss.StoneSupplier_id == 6142
            && s.Id == sss.Stone_id
            && s.Enabled == true
           let res = new { s.Name, sssName = sss.CustomStoneName == null ? s.Name : sss.CustomStoneName, sss.Id }
           group res by new { res.Name, res.sssName } into g
           select new { sssId = g.Max(_ => _.Id) };

var q = from s in Stone
        from sss in StoneSupplierStone
        where s.Id == sss.Stone_id
        && s.Enabled == true
        && sssq.Any(_ => _.sssId == sss.Id)
        orderby s.Name
        select new { s.Id, s.Name, s.Enabled, s.Tags, s.Description, s.ImageUrl, s.ImageFullUrl, StoneSupplierStoneId = sss.Id };
```

while I do get the same results, the underlying generated query looks pretty weird

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 6142
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Enabled], [t0].[Tags], [t0].[Description], [t0].[ImageUrl], [t0].[ImageFullUrl], [t1].[Id] AS [StoneSupplierStoneId]
FROM [Stone] AS [t0], [StoneSupplierStone] AS [t1]
WHERE (([t0].[Id]) = [t1].[Stone_id]) AND ([t0].[Enabled] = @p0) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX([t4].[Id2]) AS [value]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[Name], [t2].[Enabled], [t3].[Id] AS [Id2], [t3].[StoneSupplier_id], [t3].[Stone_id], 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN [t3].[CustomStoneName] IS NULL THEN [t2].[Name]
                    ELSE CONVERT(NVarChar(256),[t3].[CustomStoneName])
                 END) AS [value]
            FROM [Stone] AS [t2], [StoneSupplierStone] AS [t3]
            ) AS [t4]
        WHERE ([t4].[StoneSupplier_id] = @p1) AND (([t4].[Id]) = [t4].[Stone_id]) AND ([t4].[Enabled] = @p2)
        GROUP BY [t4].[Name], [t4].[value]
        ) AS [t5]
    WHERE [t5].[value] = [t1].[Id]
    ))
ORDER BY [t0].[Name]
```

is there a way to rewrite my LINQ query to make it look more like the original SQL query?

P.S. I use LinqPad to test LINQ and generated query.

Comment: Why do you care about the generated SQL? Does SQL server find it hard to read?

Comment: I always care to write a better code, and not being an expert in neither LINQ or SQL I wonder if I wrote it correctly, and whether there is a better way to do it. Always learning.. :)

Comment: You can use something like a [custom LINQ provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/linq-query-optimization-by-query-rewriting-using-a-custom-iqueryable-linq-provider) but I wouldn't do it if I were you, unless you really need to optimize for performance.

Comment: What's the difference? The call to `CONVERT`?